# Create a query where the WHERE condition is parametrized

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a dataset that I want to filter based on a parametric WHERE. For instance,

```
Select *
FROM t1
Where @parameter
```

In my case I want to create a parameter that has multiple values, for instance:

```
@parameter:

Case 1: 'Where t1.Fruit=Apples and t1.Fruit=Bananas and t1.price >10'
Case 2: 't1.Fruit=Bananas and t1.price =10'
Case 3: 'Where t1.Fruit=Apples and t1.Fruit=Bananas and t1.price >15'
```

I tried using

```
DECLARE @whereCondition NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @whereCondition = 'Where t1.Fruit=Apples and t1.Fruit=Bananas and t1.price >10'

DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlQuery = '
SELECT....

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlQuery
```

but it did not work

Comment: This is ms sql server, not mysql code!

Comment: You need to add your dynamic where clause string to the SQL query string - it doesn't magically get used

Comment: "it did not work" what happened? your actual `@parameter` is wrong, as it's missing quotes on the values `'Where t1.Fruit=''Apples'' and t1.Fruit=''Bananas'' and t1.price >10'`

Comment: So, you have scratched the whole internet, but weren't able to find an example on how to use dynamic sql in sql server? Perhaps this could be a start of your journey: https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-sql-in-sql-server/

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be trying to add case parameter where clauses but the first problem is you're assigning the `WHERE` condition to `@whereCondition` but not using it. Instead you're assigning the entire query to `@sqlQuery`. To utilize the `@whereCondition` in the query, you need to concatenate it into the `@sqlQuery` string. The second issue is your `WHERE` conditions in the examples are contradictory and if `t1.Fruit=Apples` and `t1.Fruit=Bananas` it would never be true . I assume you meant to use the OR operator instead of the `AND` operator in those conditions.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
DECLARE @whereCondition NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @whereCondition = 'WHERE (t1.Fruit = ''Apples'' OR t1.Fruit = ''Bananas'') AND t1.price > 10'

DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlQuery = '
SELECT *
FROM t1
' + @whereCondition

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlQuery
```